# How do I initialize a table with data, which is stored in a list in a MAUI app?

Tags: c#, xaml, .net-6.0, maui

In my app I have a few pages and in one of them I want to initialize a table that holds some data.

My problem is that I do not know how many rows there are going to be.
The header should be static from the beginning and after the header I want a table that holds the information for the respective columns.

At the moment the XAML file looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp1.PZEAnwenderkorrekturen"
             Title="PZE Anwenderkorrekturen">
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="5,5,5,5">
        <Label Text="Kommen/Gehen" FontSize="40" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" FontFamily="Bold" />
        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Spacing="10">
            <Button Text="KOMMEN" 
                    TextColor="Black"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    WidthRequest="250" 
                    HeightRequest="150"
                    BackgroundColor="DarkSeaGreen" 
                    Clicked="Button_Clicked" 
                    BorderColor="Black" 
                    BorderWidth="2"
                    CornerRadius="50"
                    Margin="10"/>
            <Button Text="GEHEN"
                    TextColor="Black"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Large"
                    WidthRequest="250" 
                    HeightRequest="150" 
                    BackgroundColor="OrangeRed" 
                    Clicked="Button_Clicked_1" 
                    BorderColor="Black" 
                    BorderWidth="2"
                    CornerRadius="50"
                    Margin="10"/>
        </StackLayout>
            
        <!-- The table should be here -->
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray">
        </StackLayout>
    
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray">
            <Label Text="Hier ist der dritte Bereich"></Label>
        </StackLayout>

        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="LightGray">
            <Label Text="Hier ist der vierte Bereich"></Label>
        </StackLayout>

    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

So I created a new `Buchung` class like this:

```cs
public class Buchung
{
    public string Tag { get; set; }
    public DateTime Datum { get; set; }
    public string Von { get; set; }
    public string Bis { get; set; }
    public string Fehlgrund { get; set; }
    public string Anw { get; set; }
    public string Soll { get; set; }
    public string GLZ { get; set; }
    public string Gesamt { get; set; }
}
```

And after I had the `Buchung` class, I started to create instances of it in a ViewModel like this:

```cs
public class BuchungenViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<Buchung> Buchungs { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<Buchung>
    {
        new Buchung
        {
            Tag = "Montag",
            Datum = DateTime.Today,
            Von = "07:00",
            Bis ="17:00",
            Anw = "10:00",
            Soll = "08:00",
            GLZ = "02:00",
            Gesamt = "10:00"
        },
        new Buchung
        {
            Tag = "Dienstag",
            Datum = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1),
            Von = "09:00",
            Bis ="17:00",
            Anw = "08:00",
            Soll = "08:00",
            GLZ = "00:00",
            Gesamt = "08:00"
        },
        new Buchung
        {
            Tag = "Mittwoch",
            Datum = DateTime.Today.AddDays(2),
            Von = "07:00",
            Bis ="12:00",
            Anw = "05:00",
            Soll = "08:00",
            GLZ = "-03:00",
            Gesamt = "05:00"
        }
    };
}
```

The table header should look something like this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Tag" TextColor="Beige" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Tertiary}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Header" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="2,2,2,2"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="Datum" TextColor="Beige" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Tertiary}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Header" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="2,2,2,2"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" Text="Fehlzeiten" TextColor="Beige" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Tertiary}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Header" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="2,2,2,2"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="3" Text="Von" TextColor="Beige" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Tertiary}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Header" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="2,2,2,2"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="4" Text="Bis" TextColor="Beige" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Tertiary}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Header" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="2,2,2,2"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="5" Text="Anw" TextColor="Beige" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Tertiary}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Header" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="2,2,2,2"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="6" Text="Soll" TextColor="Beige" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Tertiary}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Header" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="2,2,2,2"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="7" Text="GLZ" TextColor="Beige" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Tertiary}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Header" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="2,2,2,2"></Label>
    <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="8" Text="Gesamt" TextColor="Beige" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Tertiary}" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Header" FontAttributes="Bold" Margin="2,2,2,2"></Label>
</Grid>
```

Jason mentioned something with a `BindableLayout`, so I tried this:

```xml
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Buchungs}" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Label Text="{Binding .}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Body" FontAttributes="None" Margin="2,2,2,2"></Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

But it is still not working.
If someone could help me with that, I would re6aly appriciate it.

Comment: use a [Bindable Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/layouts/bindablelayout?view=net-maui-7.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `BindableLayout` is a good approach here, as Jason recommended.

You need to make sure that you bind the data correctly. Instead of passing `.` to the binding, which means the entire object, you need to bind to a specific property of the object, e.g. `Tag`, because the `Label`'s `Text` property expects a `string`, not `Buchung`:

```xml
<StackLayout BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Buchungs}" Orientation="Horizontal">
    <BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Buchung">
            <Label Text="{Binding Tag}" TextColor="Black" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalTextAlignment="Center" FontSize="Body" FontAttributes="None" Margin="2,2,2,2"></Label>
        </DataTemplate>
    </BindableLayout.ItemTemplate>
</StackLayout>
```

Note that you might want to change the `Orientation` of the `StackLayout` to `Vertical` or directly use the `VerticalStackLayout` and place a `HorizontalStackLayout` or a `Grid` inside the `DataTemplate` to position the different properties of your data horizontally.

This is just to display the data. You'll still need to add the layout for the table header.